# How to find out register sizes of Intel Processors

Tags: cpu, intel-core-i7, intel-core-i5, intel-pentium

I'm wondering about the register sizes of the three following intel processers.

1. i7-2920XM
2. i5-2540M
3. G6960

I've been to Intel's specs and also have gone through the datasheet. But I couldn't seem to be able to find it anywhere.

Even if you couldn't find them for me, it'd be a great help if you could point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: An answer like "[64 bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64_bit)" will probably generate 10+ upvotes.

Comment: Which registers are you referring to? User-accessible registers, Data registers, Address registers, Conditional registers, General purpose registers (GPRs), Floating point registers (FPRs), Constant registers, Vector registers, etc.?  What do you mean by 'size'? Number of each type of register, or the actual data space in each (type of) register?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The i5 and the i7 are x64 processors, so they have 64-bit integer registers, 80-bit floating point registers, and 128-bit vector registers. You probably don't care about things like status registers.

As for the [G6960](http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=46483), its registers are about this big: |<------>|

Comment: @ArcaneEngineer - If you have additional information to share you should provide that in your own answer.  This question was written 4 years ago, features of newer architectures since then isn't relevant to the question.

Comment: Why do you think x64 refers to 64 bit size of integer ? Who and why it is like it ?  I heard x64 refers to size of address bus(?)